# German Math Olympiad Regional Round 21/22

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Today, I was in German Math Olympiad Regional Round  21/22 (Grade 10) There were 4 questions to answer, and I am going to show you the fourth question, which I was struggled with. [Translation is not accurate] [Source: Task 611034] [Calculators not allowed] It would be really grateful if you would comment on my solution.

**Question:** In soccer, there is a "penalty kick", in which 2 teams choose 5 players to kick 11 meter kick. We will call those teams Team A and Team B. Firstly, the first player of the Team A kicks 11 meter kick. And then, the first player of the Team B kicks 11 meter kick. And then, the second player of the Team B kicks 11 meter kick. So on and on. Every player in Team A scores a goal with a probability with 2/3, meanwhile every player in Team B scores a goal with a probability of 1/3.If one team won't be able to catch up the score of their opponent team, the game ends. (For example, when the Team A scores 3:0 after 3rd shoot of the Team B, Team B won't be able to catch up the team A, even if they would score coming rounds. Therefore, the game will be stopped, and 4th and 5th players of the both teams don't get a chance to shoot.)

Lionel is the fifth player of the Team A. Calculate the probability, that Lionel scores a golden goal. (If Lionel scores the goal, the game ends, the fifth player of the Team B won't get a chance to score a goal)

**My answer:** There are in total 9 possible scores, when 4th kick of both teams have finished -

- 0:0, 1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4
- 1:0, 2:1, 3:2, 4:3
- Score difference of 2 is not possible because the winner team will be already decided after fourth kick, and Lionel don't get chance to kick.

There are 4 total probabilities of increment:

- Probability A => Team A gets a point, team B don't => 2/3 * 2/3 = 4/9
- Probability B => Team A gets a point, team B too => 2/3 * 1/3 = 2/9
- Probability C => Team A doesn't get a point, team B too => 1/3 * 2/3 = 2/9
- Probability D => Team A doesn't get a point, team B gets a point = > 1/3 * 1/3 = 1/9

*Case #1: 0:0*

This is just
$$P(0:0) = C^4 = (\frac{2}{9})^4$$

*Case #2: 1:1*

It gets more complex from here. There are in total 2 possibilities:

*Case #2.1: One round, both teams get each one point, and none for rest of the kicks*

$$P_1(1:1) = 4 B C^3 = 4 (\frac{2}{9})^4$$

*Case #2.2: One round, team A gets a point, another round, team B gets a point, and none for rest of the kicks*

$$P_2(1:1) = 12 AC^2D = 12 (\frac{2}{9})^4$$

$$\therefore P(1:1) = 16(\frac{2}{9})^4$$

*Case #3: 2:2*

It is even more complex here! There are in total 3 possibilities:

*Case #3.1: Two rounds, both teams get each one point, and none for rest of the kicks*

$$P_1(2:2) = 6 B^2C^2 = 6 (\frac{2}{9})^4$$

*Case #3.2: One round, both teams get each one point, one round, Team A gets a point, one round, Team B gets a point, and none for a round*

$$P_2(2:2) = 24 ABCD = 24 (\frac{2}{9})^4$$

*Case #3.3: Two rounds, Team A gets a point, two rounds, Team B gets a Point*

$$P_3(2:2) = 6 A^2D^2 = 6 (\frac{2}{9})^4$$

$$\therefore P(3:3) = 36(\frac{2}{9})^4$$

*Case #4 + #5: 3:3 and 4:4*

Since the probability of both teams scoring and not scoring is equal, we can say

$$P(3:3) = P(1:1) = 16 (\frac{2}{9})^4; P(4:4) = P(0:0) = (\frac{2}{9})^4$$

*Case #6: 1:0*

One round, team A gets a point, and none for rest of the kicks.

$$P(1:0) = 4AC^3 = 4 \frac{4}{9} (\frac{2}{9})^3 = 8 (\frac{2}{9})^4$$

*Case #7: 2:1*

Last complex probability calculation:

*Case #7.1: One round, team A gets a point, one round, both teams gets a point, and none for rest of the kicks*

$$P_1(2:1) = 12ABC^2 = 12 \frac{4}{9} \frac{2}{9} (\frac{2}{9})^2 = 24(\frac{2}{9})^4$$

*Case #7.2: Two rounds, team A gets a point, one round, team B gets a point, and none for one round*

$$P_2(2:1) = 12A^2CD = 12 (\frac{4}{9})^2 \frac{2}{9} \frac{1}{9} = 24(\frac{2}{9})^4$$

$$\therefore P(2:1) = 48(\frac{2}{9})^4$$

*Case #8 + #9: 3:2 and 4:3*

Like cases #4 and #5,

$$P(3:2) = P(2:1) = 48(\frac{2}{9})^4; P(4:3) = P(1:0) = 8 (\frac{2}{9})^4$$

Therefore, P(Total) can be written as:
$$P(Total) = (\frac{2}{9})^4 (1 + 16 + 36 + 16 + 1 + 8 + 48 + 48 + 8) = 182(\frac{2}{9})^4$$

From here, Lionel should shoot a goal. If he scores a goal, his goal will be the golden goal, and Team A will win. Probability of him scoring the golden goal is:

$$P(GoldenGoalOfLionel) = P(Total) * \frac{2}{3} = 182\frac{2}{3}(\frac{2}{9})^4 \approx 29.59\%$$

Once again, thank you for reading this! Let me know my errors in the comment section!

Comment: Can you explain why you consider $0:0$ after 4 rounds? If Lionel scores a goal, then we'd still have to let Team B player 5 score right?

Comment: @CalvinLin More generally, the only case in which Lionel can score the golden goal is the case in which his team enters the fifth round with a one-goal lead.

Comment: @RobertShore I agree. However, that's not what OP has in his solution.

Comment: Clarification requested: "Firstly, the first player of the Team A kicks 11 meter kick. And then, the first player of the Team B kicks 11 meter kick. And then, the second player of the Team B kicks 11 meter kick."  Is this a **typo**?  Should the last sentence in the excerpt be: " And then, the second player of the Team **A** kicks 11 meter kick" ?

Comment: @CalvinLin in the question, it says " If Lionel scores the goal, the game ends, the fifth player of the Team B won't get a chance to score a goal "

Comment: @프로형: Won't get a chance  only if team B can't catch up! Golden goal means team B can't catch up !

Comment: Note: true blue anil's original answer, which you have accepted, is not correct. It contains an error, which I pointed out in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the completion of $8$ kicks, the scores for $A-B$ must be

$1-0,\;2-1,\;3-2,\;or\; 4-3$

Denoting the probability of a win by $A$ by *p*, and that for $B$ by *q*, the probabilities [work out to](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28binom%284%2C1%29pq%5E3%29%28binom%284%2C0%29q%5E0p%5E4%29+%2B%28binom%284%2C2%29p%5E2q%5E2%29%28binom%284%2C1%29qp%5E3%29+%2B+%28binom%284%2C3%29p%5E3q%5E1%29%28binom%284%2C2%29q%5E2p%5E2%29+%2B%28binom%284%2C4%29p%5E4q%5E0%29%28binom%284%2C3%29q%5E3p%5E1%29)

$\binom41pq^3\binom40q^0p^4 +\binom42p^2q^2\binom41qp^3 + \binom43p^3q^1\binom42q^2p^2 +\binom44p^4q^0\binom43q^3p^1$

$=56p^5q^3$

Multiplying by *p* for the golden goal,

we get $56p^6q^3$, and putting in $p =\frac23, q = \frac13$,

ans $≈0.182086$

Comment: The first 8 kicks are 4 kicks by each team. Your calculations should have $\binom{4}{k}$ for each team, not $\binom{8}{k}$. The final answer should be $\frac{x}{3^9}$

Comment: @DanielMathias: Thanks, edited !!